# Asserting model object attributes

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have this test code in a Spring controller test

```
Student student = studentService.getByNumber(767001);
    student.setCourseRights(courseRightService.getCourseRights(student));
    model.addAttribute("student", student);


    Student s = (Student) model.asMap().get("student");
```

How can I get my hands on students attributes to assert them?

```
    Assert.assertEquals(1, rights.size());   

List<GrantedCourseRight> rights = (List<GrantedCourseRight>) model.asMap().get("student.courseRights");
```

is not working, allthought student.courseRight variable is presented on a jsp page. Do I just have to put the list on model separately?

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Test](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) project provides a whole set of features to allow you to test your Spring application in Junit.  Basically, you want to establish your application context prior to running the Junit test, which will allow you to use dependency injection to inject a bean of your service.

To establish this support we annotate our test class with several Spring annotations.

**MyUnitTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@Transactional
public class SkillRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    SkillRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findOneTest(){
        Skill skill = repository.findOne(1);
        assertNotNull(skill);
        assertEquals("Java", skill.getName());
    }
}
```

When the test is ran, Spring will look in same directory for a Spring configuration file named `MyUnitTest-context.xml`.  It simply suffixes `-context.xml` to your test classes name in a first attempt to find the application context.  The @ContextConfiguration annotation also contains an element that can be used to locate your application context.

Comment: I'm using JMock, not real repos.